# Intel Dual Band Wireless-AC 3168 - Bluetooth in Debian 10 don't work

Tags: linux, drivers, debian, bluetooth, kernel

I have gigabyte brix GB-BLCE-4105 ( http://www.gigabyte.pl/products/page/desktop_platform/gb-blce-4105rev_10#kf) with card Intel® Dual Band Wireless-AC 3168.

I have installed Debian 10 and have problem with Bluetooth.

It is not visible to the system

System info:

```
Debian version: 10
Kernel: 5.6.14-2~bpo10+1 (2020-06-09) x86_64 GNU/Linux
firmware-iwlwifi version: 20190717-2~bpo10+1
```

lspci:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Device 31f0 (rev 03)
00:00.3 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Device 3190 (rev 03)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 3185 (rev 03)
00:0e.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Device 3198 (rev 03)
00:0f.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Celeron/Pentium Silver Processor Trusted Execution Engine Interface (rev 03)
00:12.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Device 31e3 (rev 03)
00:13.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 31da (rev f3)
00:13.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 31db (rev f3)
00:15.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Device 31a8 (rev 03)
00:1c.0 SD Host controller: Intel Corporation Celeron/Pentium Silver Processor SDA Standard Compliant SD Host Controller (rev 03)
00:1e.0 SD Host controller: Intel Corporation Device 31d0 (rev 03)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Device 31e8 (rev 03)
00:1f.1 SMBus: Intel Corporation Celeron/Pentium Silver Processor Gaussian Mixture Model (rev 03)
01:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-AC 3168NGW [Stone Peak] (rev 10)
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)
```

Comment: Hello, @GAD3R i do everything from this instruction but still i don't see Bluetooth only WIFI :(

Comment: It's working :)! I miss to install bluez :D Thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't mark @GAD3R answer so there is instruction:

1. Do everything in:
   https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/403739/how-to-enable-the-wi-fi-network-adapter-intel-ac-3168-in-ubuntu/403752#403752
2. Type: sudo dmesg and check if you see:

```
[   39.779681] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: loaded firmware version 22.361476.0 3168-22.ucode op_mode iwlmvm
[   39.817447] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[   39.817469] NET: Registered protocol family 31
[   39.817470] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   39.817475] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   39.817482] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   39.817486] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized

[   40.004841] Bluetooth: hci0: read Intel version: 370810225019140f34
[   40.004846] Bluetooth: hci0: Intel device is already patched. patch num: 34
```

3. Install apt-get install bluez
4. type: hcitool scan - if you see scanning... It works :)!